# Mypy errors when using ArrayLike

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, python-typing

I don't understand how I should be using ArrayLike in my code. If check mypy, I keep getting errors when I try to use the variables for anything without calling cast. I am trying to define function signatures that work with ndarray as well as regular lists.

For example, the code below

```python
import numpy.typing as npt
import numpy as np

from typing import Any

def f(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> int:
    return len(a)

def g(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> Any:
    return a[0]

print(f(np.array([0, 1])), g(np.array([0, 1])))
print(f([0, 1]), g([0, 1]))
```

give me theses errors for f() and g():

```
Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Union[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]], _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]], bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes, _NestedSequence[Union[bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes]]]"; expected "Sized"  [arg-type]

Value of type "Union[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]], _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]], bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes, _NestedSequence[Union[bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes]]]" is not indexable  [index]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of [`numpy.typing.ArrayLike`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.ArrayLike) is to be able to annotate

> objects that can be coerced into an [`ndarray`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray).

With that purpose in mind, they [defined the type](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.3/numpy/_typing/_array_like.py#L72) to be the following union:

```py
Union[
    _SupportsArray[dtype[Any]],
    _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]],
    bool,
    int,
    float,
    complex,
    str,
    bytes,
    _NestedSequence[Union[bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes]]
]
```

[`_SupportsArray`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.3/numpy/_typing/_array_like.py#L38) is simply a protocol with an `__array__` method. It neither requires `__len__` (for use with the `len` function) nor `__getitem__` (for indexing) to be implemented.

[`_NestedSequence`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.3/numpy/_typing/_nested_sequence.py#L20) is a more restrictive protocol that *does* actually require `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

But the problem with this code is that the parameter annotation is that **union**:

```py
import numpy.typing as npt

...

def f(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> int:
    return len(a)
```

So `a` *could* be a sequence-like object that supports `__len__`, but it *could* also be just an object that supports `__array__` and nothing else. It could even be just an `int` for example (see the union again). Therefore the call `len(a)` is unsafe.

Similarly, here the item access is not type safe because `a` might not implement `__getitem__`:

```py
...

def g(a: npt.ArrayLike) -> Any:
    return a[0]
```

So the reason it is not working for you is that it is not *meant* to be used as an annotation for things that are numpy arrays or other sequences; it is meant to be used for things that can be *turned* into numpy arrays.

---

If you want to annotate your functions `f` and `g` to take both lists and numpy arrays, you could just use a union of `list` and [`NDArray`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray) like `list[Any] | npt.NDArray[Any]`.

If you want to have a wider annotation to accommodate any type that has `__len__` and `__getitem__`, you need to define your own [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544):

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar

import numpy as np

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)


class SequenceLike(Protocol[T]):
    def __len__(self) -> int: ...
    def __getitem__(self, item: int) -> T: ...


def f(a: SequenceLike[Any]) -> int:
    return len(a)


def g(a: SequenceLike[T]) -> T:
    return a[0]


print(f(np.array([0, 1])), g(np.array([0, 1])))
print(f([0, 1]), g([0, 1]))
```

To be more precise `__getitem__` should probably also take `slice` objects, but the overloads may be overkill for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comply with the `numpy.typing` followed by suggested [settings](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html) under `mypy` config

```ini
[mypy]
plugins = numpy.typing.mypy_plugin
```